# 'align' : unrecognized extended attribute

Tags: visual-studio-2005, wdk

I was working with vc 6 and win ddk 3790.1830.

Now I have installed Visual Studio 2005 and win ddk 6001.18002.

Now when I compile my code I am getting "'align' : unrecognized extended attribute"

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not compiling DDK with Visual Studio compiler. You have to use DDK's compiler.